# Javascript string concatenation with if

Tags: javascript

How would I do the following, in order to pull the conditional value?

```
formatter: function() {return ' ' +
    '<b>Time: </b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %d, %H:%M ', this.x) + '<br />' +
    '<b>Volume: </b>' + if (this.y) {'Successful';} else { 'Failed';} + '<br />'
},},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create separate variable to store message:

```
var message = 'Failed';
if (this.y) {
    message = 'Successful';
}
```

Or use `?:` operator:

```
formatter: function() {return ' ' +
    '<b>Time: </b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %d, %H:%M ', this.x) + '<br />' +
    '<b>Volume: </b>' + (this.y ? 'Successful' : 'Failed') + '<br />'
},},
```

Answer (score 1):

As such, in place of your if:

```
(this.y ? 'Successful' : 'Failed')
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the ternary operator

```
formatter: function() {return ' ' +
    '<b>Time: </b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %d, %H:%M ', this.x) + '<br />' +
    '<b>Volume: </b>' + (this.y? 'Successful' : 'Failed') + '<br />'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the if conditions in a function where you can resolve the conditions and return the correct string

```
var "first part" + SomeMethodWithIfLogic(val) + "last part";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
formatter: function() {
    if (this.y) {
      success = 'Successful'
    } else {
      success = 'Unsuccessful'
    };
    return ' ' +
    '<b>Time: </b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %d, %H:%M ', this.x) + '<br />' +
    '<b>Volume: </b>' + success + '<br />'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
formatter: function() {return ' ' +
    '<b>Time: </b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %d, %H:%M ', this.x) + '<br />' +
    '<b>Volume: </b>' + ((this.y == true) ? "Successful": "Failed") + '<br />'
},},
```

That ternary operator will allow you to insert logic into you string.

Break down: 
if this.y is true then return "Successful" else return "Failed"

[Some more information here](http://javascript.about.com/od/byexample/a/ternary-example.htm)